# How to open android application from a webpage?

Tags: javascript, android, html, ios, web

can I call my app from HTML?

for example:I can call webpage with this code correctly from my app.

**android code:**

```
  startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(
                                    "myDomain.com")));
```

and after doing something in my site, I want to open my android app again.

I find this code,

```
<a href="market://details?id=info.androidhive.slidingmenu">
```

but it's just call Market to find and install the app!

Comment: Wouldn't Android's 'Back' button let the user go back to your app?

If you want more control, you can always let the user browse the webpage inside Android's WebView inside your app. In that case, going back can be achieved by finishing the WebView activity. I cannot comment on iOS though.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You might have a look at this: https://developer.android.com/training/app-indexing/deep-linking.html

```
<activity
android:name="com.example.android.GizmosActivity"
android:label="@string/title_gizmos" >
<intent-filter android:label="@string/filter_title_viewgizmos">
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <!-- Accepts URIs that begin with "http://www.example.com/gizmos” -->
    <data android:scheme="http"
          android:host="www.example.com"
          android:pathPrefix="/gizmos" />
    <!-- note that the leading "/" is required for pathPrefix-->
    <!-- Accepts URIs that begin with "example://gizmos”
    <data android:scheme="example"
          android:host="gizmos" />
    -->
</intent-filter>
```

So your app will be started by this link:

```
<a href="example://gizmos">
```

Answer (score 1):

for iOS you can set URLSchemes that will launch the app if typed on the browser: that is for example if your app called market

market:// will launch the app

to add the URLScheme do it in the info tab :
[image]

you can handle the url options by implementing 
`application:willFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` and 
`application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` methods.

Answer (score 0):

It is no longer possible starts to Android Chrome 25 [link](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/intents)

For iOS you can read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25883113/open-ios-app-from-browser)

Answer (score -3):

You can achieve it by adding a small script in website and some changes in code. You have to make url schemes.