# How to launch an android/ios app,which is already in production, from javascript, if not present redirects to playstore/app store?

Tags: android

So there is this app already in production, now I need to create a webpage which will detect if the app is present. If so, it will launch the app, if not, it will redirect to the app store.

The problem is, since the app is already in production, I cannot make any changes to the manifest.xml to add any extra intents.

How do I go about this using javascript?

I have checked the manifest.xml file of the app. This is an excerpt from there if it is helpful :

```
<intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="@string/CFBundleURLSchemes" />
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: check new option without change in your manifest file below with firebase @Diparati sen

Comment: @VishalPatel Yes, checking that out. Have you tried it, and has it worked for you?

Comment: yes its work for me. i have tried for my app also

Answer (score 0):

i think you need to add one more line try this.

```
 <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
```

Comment: Thanks for your input! The problem is, I am not allowed to touch the manifest file. I have to do whatever I have to through javascript.

Comment: are using android studio?

Comment: No, I am using Eclipse IDE.

Comment: ok but in eclipse you can access file and change it  manually

Comment: I can change the file, but I don't have the authority to do that until and unless it is the only option. The app is already in production, making changes to its manifest is not recommended unless absolutely required. Is there no other way I could do the app detection, without touching the manifest.xml?

Comment: if your application is in app store recently and you have to update it then you can change your xml file and generate new apk and upload to play store there is no other way

Comment: Thanks so much for your input.

Comment: welcome you can follow @nitinpatel answer may be help you

Comment: This is another excerpt from the manifest.xml file. Will this do?

`<intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>`

Comment: ya its correct for launching activity or home activity

Comment: But do I need to add anything to this intent filter for it to work for the app detection? I am sorry if I am sounding confused, because I really am new to this.

Comment: have you look this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31404341/how-to-open-android-application-from-a-webpage or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3469908/make-a-link-in-the-android-browser-start-up-my-app

Comment: also look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6139508/launching-an-android-application-from-the-browser or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21663001/launching-custom-android-application-from-android-browser-chrome

Answer (score 0):

I think below links will help you for your problem..

[how-to-open-android-application-from-a-webpage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31404341/how-to-open-android-application-from-a-webpage)

[open-android-application-from-a-web-page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11773958/open-android-application-from-a-web-page)

Comment: Thanks for your inputs! Although, I saw that according to both the threads, the manifest file needs to be changed. So is that the only option?

Comment: I have not tried yet, but as per my knowledge and experience, add that code(<intent-filter..) in AndroidManifest.xml. Yes, you have to add that and try it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's good Question most of the people do more stuff for that.
But `google-firebase` provide one `service` that's call "[Dynamic Links](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/)".

Dynamic link having lots of use but `you can try it for your problem`.

lets having some easy setup for that

**1)** Open firebase and make a project for it.
after that select dynamic link option.

[image]

**2)** Add your app in firebase and complete the configuration.

[image]

**3)**  setup with your play-store URL.

and select "Define link behavior for Android" option. make whatever you want.

[image]

**4)**  after completing all process

[image]

**5)**  this generated link  is all about with your **PACKAGE-NAME**
so whenever you click on webpage Link from mobile. it have automatically created two options.

- if app available in  mobile open app
- if app not available in mobile open playstore with your app.

Happy coding :)

Comment: Thanks, looks quite good! However, when I try to create a new project in firebase, I get the following error :

`There was an unknown error while processing the request. Try again.`

Do you know why that is?

Comment: The project got created by using incognito browser. Trying it out now. Is using Android Studio mandatory for Firebase to work?