# How to launch an android app from website

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs

I have an android application, which I want to launch from the website.

Here is the condition: If user had installed that app previously then give the option to open it, if not then go to the play store.

I used this code in my website:

```
<a href="myapp://link">Click me</a>
```

It is working fine.

Now what I want that when a user searches my website on Google and the link appears, if someone clicks on that link it will open the app.

As well as this code:

```
<a href="myapp://link">Click me</a>
```

is not working if I put this into a function like:

```
launchApp:function(){
  $window.location.href='myapp://link';
}
```

this is not working.

How do I fix these issues?

Comment: Does `<a href="myapp://link">Click me</a> ` work or not? You just said it twice that it works and then that it doesn't

Comment: read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31404341/how-to-open-android-application-from-a-webpage

Comment: are you using an emulator for testing?

Comment: <a href="myapp://link">Click me</a> work, but not when I put his into function

Answer (score 0):

Create an Intent filter for the main activity/ the activity which you want to open, something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31404717/7527995