# How to open application in mobile on click of a link?

Tags: php, android, ios

I have a mobile application for my website and when user register we send them confirmation email.So when user click on confirmation link from mobile device we want to open application instead of browser.

Comment: do some minimum searching

Comment: I done but not get any help.

Comment: https://www.google.co.in/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=open+android+from+web+page&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gfe_rd=cr&ei=MSprWNmXFMaL8Qe8opvYAg#channel=fs&q=open+android+app+from+browser

Comment: Yes it is only for android and what about ios ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25883113/open-ios-app-from-browser

Comment: This is what you are exactly looking for http://stackoverflow.com/a/21727055/5476209

Answer (score 0):

You can use `android:scheme` to specify your app to be opened from the special link.

In your manifest add

```
<intent-filter>
    <data android:scheme="your.scheme" />
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
</intent-filter>
```

In your website add the link like this:

```
<a href="your.scheme://other/parameters/">
```

your app will be launched automatically as this is the only app that handles `your.scheme://` type of `URIs`

Caution: If the user doesn't have the app installed they will get an error.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Firebase Dynamic Links](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/).

When a user opens one of your Dynamic Links, if your app isn't yet installed, the user is sent to the Play Store or App Store to install your app (unless you specify otherwise), and your app opens. You can then retrieve the link that was passed to your app and handle the link as appropriate for your app.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Jaymin.But it is possible to do this without using Firebase?

Comment: That I had not researched about because I have used firebase it provides all the features

Answer (score 0):

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2958870/5476209)
answer fully explained for android as well as what you should do from web side.