# Open External Link In Phonegap App

Tags: android, ios, cordova

so I'm developing a small online store using Phonegap. Currently I have a website for the store so the users can see the products offered. I want to add a button inside the products page so I can open the product inside the app.

For example, I have the following product with this url `www.mysite.com/?product=55` I want to open this same url inside the Phonegap App in Android and iOS.

Any idea as to how to do this? Any help is greatly appreciated. :D

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Open iOS app from browser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25883113/open-ios-app-from-browser)

Comment: Will your referred answer work in Android and iOS Phonegap Apps?

Comment: This is the answer that you want for android- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/525063/android-respond-to-url-in-intent

Comment: The key word for you to search is "custom url scheme", check this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-customurlscheme