# iOS Swift Email Deep Linking

Tags: ios, swift3, xcode8, deep-linking

I need to make my users to click on email URL to open my App. I having some daily updates that I have forward to my Users. I am having some URL links in that email. I just need to make my users to open app when they clicking those email links.

Email URL Here:
http://kavin.com/login?redirect_to=calendar?cal_navigation=2017-03-23

Comment: Such a URL id impossible to handle. You need a custom scheme.

Comment: you can take help http://blog.originate.com/blog/2014/04/22/deeplinking-in-ios/ OR https://www.programmableweb.com/news/how-to-implement-deep-linking-ios/how-to/2015/07/14

After implementation if you have any question than post `comment` or change `question description`

Comment: kavin where u struck

Comment: I think your approach is similar with this.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25883113/open-ios-app-from-browser

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik I am getting struck in adding codes to appdelegate.swift file. I just don't know how to add it.

Comment: @KavinKumarArumugam - oh ok , just wait, you need the call back method correct

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik K

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use the call back method for handle the referral source

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: Any) -> Bool {

    print("source application:\(sourceApplication)")
    let value: String = url.absoluteString as String
    print("value :\(value)")
    print("scheme: \(url.scheme)")
    print("query: \(url.query)")

    return true
}
```

Comment: if you need more thing we continue

Comment: based on the value we need to push or handle the VC open/navigation

Comment: what URLSchema I need to add in info.plist file. Here is my Email Link: http://kavin.com/login?redirect_to=calendar?cal_navigation=2017-03-23

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25883274/6606820 This is what I did in my info.plist file. I have added http://kavin.com/ in my URLSchema

Comment: @KavinKumarArumugam - url schema is nothing but, may be what ever you think you can set for e.g, if I set the schema as `karthik` the call back we need to handle with karthik

Comment: Absolutely that what I asking. How to handle it

Comment: @KavinKumarArumugam - see this http://blog.originate.com/blog/2014/04/22/deeplinking-in-ios/

Answer (score 0):

Check this link to support Universal Link

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html

When you support universal links, iOS users can tap a link to your website and get seamlessly redirected to your installed app without going through Safari. If your app isn’t installed, tapping a link to your website opens your website in Safari.