# How to open a specific page of an iOS app from an URL

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, deep-linking

Am using xamarin.iOS, I want to open a particular page in my app from an URL which is sending by any e-mail, what is the method to this? I heard about deep linking of applications is this the perfect solution for this scenario? anyone help me to find a perfect solution

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43177383/ios-swift-email-deep-linking/43177914#43177914

Comment: can you share the steps following that

Answer (score 2):

Yes, deep linking is the topic that you should be looking into. Refer to
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/platform-features/deep-linking/

You can also read more on different methods here: https://blog.branch.io/universal-links-uri-schemes-app-links-and-deep-links-whats-the-difference/

You can even consider to pay for a service from [branch.io](https://branch.io/) for this linking infrastructure.

Comment: Alex from Branch.io: this is a free service — no need to pay for it. See [here](https://github.com/BranchMetrics/xamarin-branch-deep-linking) for everything you need to get started!

Answer (score 1):

Use App Links and do the magic on the magic OpenUrl override method

https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/cross-platform/app-links/app-links-ios/