Window.open doesn't work for safari mobile only for certain urls
I am trying to implement opening mobile app when the related website is opened in safari mobile browser. When I try to open other urls like youtube but it doesn't work for some other urls like apps.apple.com. It opens a new tab and doesn't put the address in new tab. I have also tried taking a reference of window.open and changing the location object at later time with setTimeout. And also creating a href property of location object with no luck.
I was expecting appstore to be opened

Is this similar to what you want? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25883113/open-ios-app-from-browser

I am able to navigate to app when the user clicks on link but it is not working when I call window.open or calling click event on anchor element mainly for some urls like appstore url
